# rpmlib(FileDigests) dependency error on SuSE

Tags: dependencies, rpm, yum, suse

Doing a **yum install A-3.6.0** on both SuSE 11.2 (64-bit) and CentOS 5.8 (64-bit) the following installation requirements error popped up:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by A-3.6.0-1.noarch
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by A-3.6.0-1.noarch
    which is needed by A-3.6.0-1.noarch
```

Googling the error shows that others have run into this problem on SuSE and CentOS, but I'm unable to find a resolution to the problem.  Does anyone know where I'm might find an rpmlib RPM that I could download and **rpm -i**? Or is there a SuSE and/or CentOS solution?  Or the URL to where the rpmlib source lives and I will a SuSE and CentOS package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your package was built with a newer version of rpmlib than you have on your CentOS and SuSE systems, one that has xz support (available in CentOS 6 and presumably some newer version of SuSE).

Do not try to get your system "fixed" for this you will almost certainly just break something.

Find a package appropriate to your distributions instead.

Comment: So, it has nothing to do with the requires: tag listing the following: **rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1,** rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1, rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1, **rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 4.6.0-1,** cyrus-sasl-gssapi, cyrus-sasl-plain, libxml2, libxslt, zlib, sqlite, rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1, redhat-lsb-core, /bin/bash, /usr/bin/env, which, bash, /bin/sh

Comment: If you see a `Requires:` line in a spec file that lists `rpmlib` lines like that I'd be **very** surprised. To the best of my knowledge those are automatic requirements added by rpm when it creates the package based on the rpmlib features it has used. So `rpmlib(PayloadIsXz)`, for example, means the contents of the rpm package are compressed with `xz` rather than `gzip`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768793/rpmlibfiledigests-dependency-error-on-rpm-built-with-rpm-maven-plugin) may help you as well.  You just have to provide some parameters, either on the command line or by modifying either the global or local macros file on your system :

```
%_binary_payload    w9.gzdio
%_binary_filedigest_algorithm   1
```

Apparently, as I detail in my answer on the other question, the stock macros file provided by redhat claims that these parameters are the defaults, but if that were the case, you wouldn't have to comment them out to get them.

Comment: Would the person who downvoted my attempt to be helpful be so kind as to explain why?

Answer (score 1):

This one is quite old, but I just ran into the same problem on SLES11.4 (or at least a similar one):

```
user@machine:~> sudo /bin/rpm -f -U --oldpackage /tmp/local_python27.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by local_python27-2.7.14-3.x86_64
```

for me installing with `zypper` instead of `rpm` worked:

```
user@machine:~> sudo zypper install /tmp/local_python27.rpm
```

Not sure if zypper also can deal with the missing xz support though.