# rpmlib(FileDigests) dependency error on RPM built with rpm-maven-plugin

Tags: dependencies, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin

Just like with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775285/rpmlibfiledigests-dependency-error-on-suse), I try to an install an RPM and get the following errors:

```
# rpm -iv myapp-0.0.14-SNAPSHOT.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by myapp-0.0.14-SNAPSHOT20151117233758.noarch
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by myapp-0.0.14-SNAPSHOT20151117233758.noarch
```

But my app was built with the [rpm-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/index.html).

There are differences in redhat version between the build machine and the server on which I want to do the install.

```
$ uname -a
Linux buildmach 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 1 18:23:37 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# uname -a
Linux myserver 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:39 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How do I resolve this, If I am using this plugin to build the rpm?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it's not that hard, at least not for my use case where I'm basically just using rpm to deploy war files.

You merely need to define a couple of macros differently than what the stock redhat installer gives you:

```
%_binary_payload    w9.gzdio
%_binary_filedigest_algorithm   1
```

Interestingly, redhat's macros file for rhel6 indicates that these are the default but they're not, in fact, the defaults:

```
#   Compression type and level for source/binary package payloads.
#       "w9.gzdio"  gzip level 9 (default).
#       "w9.bzdio"  bzip2 level 9.
#       "w7.xzdio"  xz level 7, xz's default.
#       "w7.lzdio"  lzma-alone level 7, lzma's default
#
#%_source_payload   w9.gzdio
#%_binary_payload   w9.gzdio

#   Algorithm to use for generating file checksum digests on build.
#   If not specified or 0, MD5 is used.
#   WARNING: non-MD5 is backwards incompatible, don't enable lightly!
#   The supported algorithms may depend on NSS version, as of NSS
#   3.11.99.5 the following are supported:
#   1   MD5 (default)
#   2   SHA1
#   8   SHA256
#   9   SHA384
#   10  SHA512
#
#%_source_filedigest_algorithm  1
#%_binary_filedigest_algorithm  1
```

If the defaults were as indicated by the comments in the redhat macros file, it should not be necessary to uncomment these lines.

In any case, since I'm using the rpm-maven-plugin, I can configure this using plugin parameters in pom.xml without changing the macros file.

```
<defineStatements>
    <defineStatement>_binary_payload w9.gzdio</defineStatement>
    <defineStatement>_binary_filedigest_algorithm 1</defineStatement>
</defineStatements>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those "differences in redhat version" that you so casually sweep aside are *huge* and, exactly the problem. CentOS 5 and CentOS 6 have wildly different versions of rpm (and rpmlib) and the CentOS 6 version has support for newer payload compression and a newer `FileDigests` version than the version of rpm (and rpmlib) on CentOS 5 can support.

This is exactly what I said in the answer to the question you linked. You cannot build a package on CentOS 6 for use on CentOS 5 without using a chroot of some sort.

Well, I believe you might be able to override the default selection of compression and digest algorithms via rpmbuild macro configuration and selecting values that are supported in the version of rpm that is available on CentOS 5 *might* remove those requirements from your build RPM (or lower the version so that it works) but I don't know how to do that offhand.

Comment: @Etan_Reisner I wasn't so much as dismissing those OS version differences as proposing them as the likely culprit.  I was looking for a way around this - either through the rpm-maven-plugin or by changing some configuration files for the underlying rpm system that the plugin invokes.  I know this must be possible.  My organization currently is building rpms using nmake - on a Solaris machine no less! - that are somehow ported to many different destination boxes, Solaris, many versions of RHEL, etc.  I'm not sure if the people who designed all this are still with the company.

Comment: Forward-porting is (generally) more possible then backwards. I can virtually *guarantee* that the version of rpm in use on that current Solaris machine is as old as (and quite possibly older than) the version of rpm on CentOS 5, etc. Please correct me if I am wrong about that. You are free to check the rpmrc/macro configuration files on the Solaris host and see if they are setting compat options specifically (like I said that should be possible).

Comment: I actually found it easy to get this to work by adjusting the macros.